# Google Drive - push notifications content update - download

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have an application where user stores files (on the server) and on it's own google drive. I would like to reflect document changes from drive to server files. The only way of achieving this I could think of is using push notifications api for drive files and if type of notification is content update to download and replace file on server side. Is there a better way of achieving this, since notifications are being received often (almost for each letter typed) and downloading file every second doesn't seem like optimal solution.

Comment: You could pole the file once a day or something.  That's about your only option if your not happy with the number of notifications you get from Push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways in which you can handle this ...

1. You can poll the Google Drive server for its state every minute. Figure out what changed and download it. [This](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-changes) can help.
2. You can also use an existing [tool](https://github.com/jasonliu19/DriveSync) or [another](https://github.com/jasonliu19/DriveSync) one to solve this problem.